# SQL Query for multiple tables (foreign keys involved)

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have 5 tables in MySQL database. Some of them share foreign keys and are interdependent of each other. I am trying to create a query that will show all the results side by side(`major`, `course`, `semester`, etc). The query I created query it is not displaying my desired results since I have not added the other tables. I am not sure how to implement the other tables.  How can I modify the mysql-query to display all the results in order?

**Query**

```
select * from course left join major on course.id = majors.id left join majors on courses_major_xref.majors_id = majors.id
```

Comment: Your query doesn't match the structure in the image.  Which is correct?

Comment: @G-Nugget Sorry I did some modification but the image is the correct one

Comment: You might want to standardize the names of the ID columns; that will make writing `JOIN`s easier.  Instead of writing `SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.table1_id)` you can just write `SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING (table1_id)`.  Long queries with multiple joins are much easier to write like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT * FROM course 
INNER JOIN major_courses_xref ON course.id = major_courses_xref.course_id 
INNER join majors ON major_courses_xref.majors_id = majors.id 
INNER JOIN courses_semester_xref ON course.id = courses_semester_xref.course_id 
INNER JOIN semester ON courses_semester_xref.semester_id = semester.id;
```

Comment: By using inner joins you are going to miss courses that do not have a link to semesters and majors which is fine if that's what you the OP wants, but judging by his/her query example I'm guessing that all courses are desired, whether the other info is available or not.

Comment: he will receive only the course details which have been taken. if OP need all info, he can change inner join to 'left join'. thx

Comment: Alright, I now understand the difference between `Inner` and `Left`. You answered specifically as I asked but One extra modification: How can I omit from the display result `course_id` `major_id` `semester_id`?

Comment: simple: just remove the * from query and put name of the fields u want. ex. select course.id, course.code, course.description, course.hours from course......

Answer (score 0):

I think there is just some order of operations problems in your query, try:

```
SELECT * from course
LEFT JOIN major_course_xref
ON course.id = major_course_xref.courseID
LEFT JOIN major 
ON major.id = major_course_xref.major_id 
LEFT JOIN course_semester_xref
ON course.id = course_semester_xref.course_id
LEFT JOIN semester
ON course_semester_xref.semester_id = semester.id
```